# Массивы в C++ , наименьшее число цифр

Tags: c++, арифметика

Всем привет , у меня есть задание , нужно сделать квадратную символьную матрицу порядка n и определить номер первой по порядку строки, содержащей наименьшее число цифр. Я вроде бы все сделал , но через раз код работает неправильно . Подскажите , что нужно изменить или как можно его просто улучшить. Мне кажется , что ошибка во второй части кода , но где именно , я не знаю. Сам код :

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int const n = 5;
int chars [n][n];
 
srand(time(NULL));
 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        chars[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        cout << chars[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
 
int row = 0;
int countRow = 0;
int countCol = 0;
 
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // ascii коды на цифры 48-57
        if(chars[i][j] > 47 && chars[i][j] < 58 ) countCol++;//
        }
    if(countRow < countCol)///
    { countRow = countCol; row = j; }//
    countCol = 0;
}
 
cout << "row number: " << row << endl; // строки индексируются с 0
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторая часть пишется примерно так (не компилировал, писал прямо в ответ):

```
int count = n*10, row = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        int a = abs(chars[i][j]);
        if (a == 0) sum += 1;
        else
            while(a) { sum++; a/=10; }
    }
    if (count > sum)
    {
        count = sum;
        row = i;
    }
}

cout << row << endl;
```

Считаете по строкам количество цифр, находите наименьшее...

Comment: спасибо))))))))